# Unable to dynamically increment a property of an object

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a dynamic canvas animation using javascript. The intent is to increment the x property of many image objects and then draw them in the x position of the updated x property each time a draw() function runs. I'm not able to successfully increment this x property though - for some reason it always resets to 0.

I defined this global array to contain all the objects I will draw:

```
window.character = [];
```

I have this object constructor to create new image objects:

```
function Character(name, x, y){
    //define the image object within the Character
    this.imageObject = new Image();
    this.imageObject.src = name+'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAW0lEQVR42mL8//8/AzpgZGTcC6KBcs5wMRwK/0MVMsLEmLAoEmXAApiwiKUhaRJCltgLsQVsWwIQ/wTx0fBeRigD7B6Y24i1mj4Kn4KI7Uie2Y7FI8+B2AMgwABjRynfWgpcxQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';

    window.character.push(this);
    window.characterPosition = window.character.indexOf(this);

    //set natural width and natural height once the image is loaded
    if (this.imageObject.addEventListener){
        this.imageObject.addEventListener('load', function(){
            window.imgWidth = this.naturalWidth/2;
            window.imgHeight = this.naturalHeight/2;

            //set natural width and natural height to object
            window.character[characterPosition]['imageObject']['w'] = window.character[characterPosition]['imageObject']['w0'] = window.imgWidth;
            window.character[characterPosition]['imageObject']['h'] = window.character[characterPosition]['imageObject']['h0'] = window.imgHeight;

            //set initial x and y position
            console.log(x);
            window.character[characterPosition]['imageObject']['x'] = x;
            window.character[characterPosition]['imageObject']['y'] = y;
            console.log(window.character[characterPosition]['imageObject']['x']);
            //set loaded property for the object once loading is done
            window.character[characterPosition]['imageObject']['loaded'] = true;

            function imageLoaded(element, index, array){
                return element['imageObject']['loaded'] == true;
            }

            //test whether every object in array has the image loaded
            if(character.every(imageLoaded)){
                $('button#play').show();
            };
        });
} //end object constructor
```

Inside that constructor function, there is some weird behavior. I created a new object using:

```
var sun0 = new Character('data:text/javascript;base64,', 12, 12);
```

Then here's what I see from the console.log messages inside the object constructor:

```
console.log(x); //returns 12, as expected
window.character[characterPosition]['imageObject']['x'] = x;
window.character[characterPosition]['imageObject']['y'] = y;
console.log(window.character[characterPosition]['imageObject']['x']); //returns 0. Thought it would be 12
```

Ultimately, here's how I intend to animate the object across the screen. This draw() function runs on an interval every 10ms.

```
function draw(){
    clear();

    //draw characters
    drawCharacter(window.character[0]['imageObject'],window.character[0]['imageObject']['x'],window.character[0]['imageObject']['y'],window.character[0]['imageObject']['w'],window.character[0]['imageObject']['h']);
    window.character[0]['imageObject']['x'] += 10;
    console.log(window.character[0]['imageObject']['x']); //returning 0 every time, not incrementing the way I expected it to.
}
```

How can I get this 'x' property to increment?

[here's the JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrengy/seb3kn4z/embedded/result/)

Comment: You can save yourself some typing when referring to object properties whose names you know statically by using the `.` operator instead of `[ ]` - `window.character[0].imageObject.x` for example

Comment: perhaps first, verify that you are `console.log`ging the right character?

Comment: An addendum to Pointy's comment; if you save a reference to `this` instance (ie: `var character = this;`), other than pushing it into the characters array, you don't have to keep referencing `window.characters;` the array has a reference to `character`, thus you can just change the properties on `character` directly, and any subsequent lookups via `window.characters[i]` are going to reflect the current state of `character` currently referenced at that index.

Comment: `Image` elements have `x` and `y` properties natively, and they cannot be modified.

Comment: @sg.cc yes, i am definitely logging the right character - see the back to back `console.log(x);` and then `window.character[characterPosition]['imageObject']['x'] = x;` and then `console.log(window.character[characterPosition]['imageObject']['x']);`. The first and the last give different values.

Comment: For what it's worth, all those global variables are really a terrible idea.

Comment: @Pointy why are all the global variables a bad idea? And do you mean defining them as global variables or just referring to them by window.characters? And how would I reference them outside of the function in which they are created without using global variables?

Comment: Global variables are *generally* considered to be problematic. Because of the way JavaScript works, they can very often be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointy answered your question in the comments, but to expand on this... you're trying to set `x` on an `Image` which can't be set. For instance, try this in your browser's console:

```
var img = new Image();
img.x = 1;
console.log(img.x); // this will be zero
```

That's effectively what you're doing. Additionally, in your code try changing `['x']` to `['myX']` and then it will work as expected.